# flutter_google_places: ^0.2.1 plugin error in pubspec.yaml file

Tags: dart, flutter

Getting error in pubspec.yaml file with flutter_google_places: ^0.2.1 plugin like below:
How can i get rid of this type of issues in flutter.

**Note: There is no indentation for the package**

> Error on line 18, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
>     flutter_google_places: ^0.2.1
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: flutter_google_places
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_google_places: ^0.2.1
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 19):

You can't have a dependency that has the same name as your project

```
name: flutter_google_places
```

You need to change the `name: ...`

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem quite similar... because I created the project named "Flutter_modular" and I tried to insert the "flutter_modular" in my pubspec.yaml.

```dart
dependencies: 
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_modular:
```

The project name can't be the same as the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael Yes, The project name can't be the same as the dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Project name and dependency title must be different.

name:

```
 name: flutter_google_places
```

and

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_google_places: ^0.2.1
```

Don't use **project_name** and **dependency_name** same String
Example :- *pubspec.yaml* file

```
name: sqflite          //project_name
description: A new Flutter application.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
sqflite: ^1.3.1+1       //dependency_name
```

Answer (score 2):

there must be a problem with your project name. Project name cannot be as same as a package name.